# Setting a custom SelectedBackgroundView on ViewCellRenderer in Xamarin Forms has no effect

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to customise the selected background colour for the ListView on my app's slideout menu. So I have this custom ViewCellRenderer, but I still get the standard grey background on the selected item:

```
public class MenuViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
    UIView background;

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

        if (background == null)
        {
            background = new UIView
            {
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Brown
            };
        }

        cell.SelectedBackgroundView = background;

        /*
         SANITY CHECKS:

         cell.BackgroundView = background; // this works, proving that I can override SOMETHING with my renderer

         cell.MultipleSelectionBackgroundView = background; // tried this for just in case

         cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None; // has no effect

         Debug.WriteLine("I can read this in the console");  // yip
        */

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Can anyone think of a reason why this is not working?
Any suggested alternatives?

Comment: Your code works for me, but the SelectedBackgroundView only seems to be active for a short time, so I see the brown color background but it quickly fades back to the non-seletced background view. This is the default behavior for iOS. Are you looking for the cell to maintain the selected background color until another cell is selected? That can be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your very useful feedback @jgoldberger I was not quick enough to see the brown background. Your answer closes this question for me, so can you please repost as an answer so I can tick it as the resolution to the mystery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me, but the SelectedBackgroundView only seems to be active for a short time, so I see the brown color background but it quickly fades back to the non-seletced background view. This is the default behavior for iOS. Are you looking for the cell to maintain the selected background color until another cell is selected? That can be a bit more complicated.